# SQL max without group by

Tags: sql, group-by, max, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to get one row with the maximum date. I cannot use group by as I need to retrieve all data in that row.

I have this:

```
ID     Date          Country
1      05/05/2019    US
2      05/06/2019    UK
```

I want to get this:

```
ID     Date          Country
2      05/06/2019    UK
```

I've tried the below but it didn't work for me

```
select TOP 1 ID, Date, country
from table
order by Date desc
```

Comment: order by dat**e** desc

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Your query should work (assuming `data` is a typo).

Comment: Sory did a typo (changed it now).

my query did not work..

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=536c59a352cffa50949c77094b7f47eb) is a db<>fiddle that shows three different interpretations of the date in your sample data:

- as a string
- as mm/dd/yyyy
- as dd/mm/yyyy

All three of them produce the same result.

I suspect that your actual data is more complicated and you have oversimplified the example for the question.  Further, my suspicion is that the date column is stored as a *string* rather than a *date*.

As a string, you might have some hidden characters that affect the sorting (such as leading spaces).

If this is the case, fix the data type and your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
select Top 1 ID,Date, country from table where date = max(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what DB system you are using.

In Microsoft SQL server, you can use row_number() function:

```
select top 1 *
from facts
order by ROW_NUMBER() over (order by dateKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

First set the `DATE or DATETIME`  Datatype in your `[Date]` column 
then try this code:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, [Date] , country FROM TableName ORDER BY Date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID,Date,Country from TableName Where Date = MAX(Date) AND Rownum <= 1
```